# ploting multiple objects from a function in R

Tags: r, quantmod

i'm trying to a function to chart a `quantmod` chart and some rect's on top. it's working fine when running from the cmd but when wrapping inside a function either only the rect are showing , or only the graph is showing, or sometimes neither is showing.
Example code :

```
f1 <- function() { 
require(quantmod)
s <- get(getSymbols('PRGO'))["2012::"]
chart_Series(s)
u<-par("usr")
d<-data.frame(Buttom=c(100,90),Top=c(110,95))
rect(u[1],d[,'Buttom'],u[2],d[,'Top'],col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.2),border=0)
}
```

- you might need to run plot.new()
- if you return the chart object from the function and print it, it works but i haven't found a way of returning both chart object and the rect's (the rect are a list as well)
- i understand that functions work in a temporary environment - i haven't found a way of running the function in the global env. i don't know how to `assign` the rect to the `chob` in the global env.
- the function will eventually do all the plotting - i want to add more lines, labels etc'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your `chart_Series()` inside a `print` it seems to work ?

```
f1 <- function() { 
  require(quantmod)
  s <- get(getSymbols('PRGO'))["2012::"]
  print(chart_Series(s))
  u<-par("usr")
  d<-data.frame(Buttom=c(100,90),Top=c(110,95))
  rect(u[1],d[,'Buttom'],u[2],d[,'Top'],col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.2),border=0)
}

f1()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. made it work with the labels and titles as well. is it because chart_Series returns a chart object and when running from the cmd the env just prints it implicitly ? or i'm getting wrong (i've tried allot of combinations....)

Comment: Yes, that should be it. It's the same thing for `ggplot2` objects, for example.